# what will be the value of byte b=(byte)0x8A if printed?

Tags: java, android

What will b return ?

```
byte b = (byte)0x8A;
System.out.println("Value"+b);
```

What will it print? And when does the value will return a negation?

Comment: What output you got when you compile and run?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself and give us the answer, it won't take much time of yours.

Comment: I guess its -128+10, hence something like -118?

Comment: ... in other words `Value-118`

Comment: yeah i can run and find but how i dont know??? Can u explain??

Comment: Edit a little dummy program with suffix ".java", compile it with `javac`, and then run it with `java`, specifying only the non-suffix part of the file name.

Comment: when the number gets big, it wraps around the end and becomes negative.  so: 0xff = -1, 0xfe = -2, 0xfd = -3, ... all the way down to 0x80.  that is one way to think of it.  here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: @thang thanx...my basic was not clear with complements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will it print??

Probably not what you expect.  In Java a `byte` is a (signed) number not a character, so when `0x8A` is converted to a String you will get the decimal representation of a small negative number.

So I'd expect:

```
Value-118
```

---

If you wanted `0x8A` to be interpreted as a character you should write this:

```
char c = (char) 0x8A;
System.out.println("Value" + c);
```

But that doesn't really work either because the Unicode codepoint 008A is not a printing character.  (And for what it is worth, 0x8A is not ASCII because true ASCII is a 7 bit character set.)

Comment: ok so this is where there is an ambiguity in English.  is it a small negative number or a large negative number?   is -100 a large negative number or a small negative number compared to -10? :p

Comment: There is an ambiguity is english, but there is no ambiguity in mathematical english.  Small / large number refers to the magnitude of the number not its sign.

Comment: Dont know guys please explain

Comment: @thang - When *compared* mathematically, -10 is larger than -100.

Comment: I know i can print the answer but explain me how is it cuming...I need to undesratnd

Comment: @sheetal - what do you want us to explain?  Did you read the first 2 sentences of my answer?  What didn't you understand about my explanation?

Comment: but -100 can be considered a large negative number because the phrase "a [modifier] negative number" can be used to mean the magnitude of the number is [modifier].  while -10 is larger than -100, -10 is not more negative than -100, so as far as being negative goes, it is smaller.

Comment: i mean how m i getting -118 if(0x8A) is converted into byte..Even if i consider ascii whats the rest..i m not getting

Comment: @sheetal.  I explained that.  *"In Java a `byte` is a (signed) number not a character..."*

Comment: ohkk so a singned number is converted to string than how is the decimal number is decided to be -118 of any small number??

Comment: @thang - to answer your original question -100 is a large negative number compared to -10.  But I wasn't comparing -100 to -10 in my answer.  I was simply making the observation that -118 is small and negative.

Comment: -100 is small and negative, but is it a small negative number?  a "small negative number" can mean "a small number that is negative" or "a negative number that is small in its negativity".  in fact, if it were "small, negative number" (or even "small and negative number"), then it's clearly the former.  on the other hand, if it were "smally negative number", then it's clearly the latter. this can go on ad nauseam. :p